# SpelEvaluationException: EL1004E:(pos 8): Method call: Method transform(byte[]) cannot be found

Tags: spring-integration

I am trying to create a simple spring-integration app that ingests http data and forwards them to two queues.
In one of these queues (ignore the other for now) i would like to enrich the data and then forward them to an AMQP
endpoint.

My problem is the following exception:

> MessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel : Reply message received but
>   the receiving thread has exited due to an exception while sending the
>   request message:ErrorMessage
>   [payload=org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: 
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException:
>   EL1004E:(pos 8): Method call: Method transform(byte[])  cannot be
>   found on com.EnrichmentService type,

I am pretty sure that the ingested data are serialized in a way
that my enrichment service , that is meant to work on a DTO (Data in my example), cannot understand.
I tried implementing Serializable on  my DTO.

My question is, how would i debug the types flowing through my channels ?

My code looks like that:

```
@Bean
public StandardIntegrationFlow ingestRaw() {

    return IntegrationFlows.from(httpIngest())
            .headerFilter("accept-charset", "http_requestMethod")
            .publishSubscribeChannel(Executors.newCachedThreadPool(),
                    input -> input
                            .subscribe(enrichmentFlow()))
                            .subscribe(anotherFlow()))
            .get();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow enrichmentFlow(){

    return flow -> flow.enrich(e -> e
            .requestChannel(enrichmentRequestChannel())
            .replyChannel(enrichmentReplyChannel())
            .requestPayload(Message::getPayload))
            .transform(Transformers.fromJson(Data.class))
            .handle(Data.class, (payload, headers) -> enrichmentService.transform(payload))
            .handle(amqpOutboundFlow());
}


@Bean
public HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway httpIngest() {
    return Http.inboundGateway(SINK_ENDPOINT_PATH).get();
}


@Bean("enrichmentRequestChannel")
public DirectChannel enrichmentRequestChannel(){
    return MessageChannels.direct().get();
}

@Bean("enrichmentReplyChannel")
public DirectChannel enrichmentReplyChannel(){
    return MessageChannels.direct().get();
}


@Bean
public AmqpOutboundEndpoint amqpOutboundFlow() {
    return Amqp.outboundAdapter(this.amqpTemplate).routingKeyExpression("enrichOut.enrichedGroup").get();
}
```

Comment: Show, please, more stack trace for that error

Comment: M-m-m. Who is subscribed to the `enrichmentRequestChannel`? Show, please, that flow

Comment: All my code is there. As i am a newbie to spring-integration, i guess i am misissing something ...

Comment: Ok, so, where is more stack trace? And maybe you can prepare some Spring Boot application to play from my side locally?

Answer (score 0):

I made a mistake and forgot to uncomment a binding i had in use before, so the TransformationService was bound in two ways (at least it seemed).

```
 @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "enrichmentRequestChannel", outputChannel = "enrichmentReplyChannel")
 public EnrichedData transform(Data data) {
```